# JBoss Compatiblity Issue

Tags: web-services, jboss

We have developed a webservices and it is running fine on tomcat while deploying the same . We are getting below error. Help is much appreciated.

```
12:15:08,115 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/flagClarity].[filesize]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet filesize threw exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.setDocumentURI(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:893)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:141)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
        at hpd_igcinterface_create.HPDIGCInterfaceCreateService.<init>(HPDIGCInterfaceCreateService.java:47) [classes:]
        at com.flag.update.FileSizeServlet.doPost(FileSizeServlet.java:349) [classes:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_71]
```

Comment: It is giving error on Jboss

Comment: Try remove GNU gnujaxp jar from your deployment

Comment: Thanks Federico. This is working in JBOSS 4.0. However same WAR file failsing in JBoss 7.0

Comment: This has been resolved by using the below Jars                      serializer-2.7.1.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xerces-2.9.1.jar